# R - pander not passing use.hyphening = TRUE parameter

Tags: r, latex, markdown, pandoc, pander

I am using R Markdown to knit a PDF.

I am using the following to output a series of table:

```
  output_table <- pander(input_df, split.table = Inf, split.cells = paste0((100/ncol(input_df)), "%"), use.hyphening = TRUE, caption = caption)
```

Some of the strings I need to output are incredibly long (i.e. a long URL) so I need them to be hyphenated/break to fit in a cell but none of the arguments are achieving that.

This is part of my YAML header just in case anything in there could be throwing this off.

```
always_allow_html: yes
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{longtable}
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  - \usepackage{wrapfig}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{colortbl}
  - \usepackage{pdflscape}
  - \usepackage{tabu}
  - \usepackage{threeparttable}
  - \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
output:
  pdf_document:
      latex_engine: xelatex 
      template: eisvogel
      toc: true
      number_sections: true
```

How do I get the tables to wrap extra-long text into multiple lines so I can see all of it?

P.S.: Any attempts to use "pandoc.table" or passing arguments through "panderOptions" have failed by either crashing the knitting process, returning NULL in place of tables and Quitting for the lines where tables are created.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post a small example to demonstrate the issue and for us to play with?